# "symbol's function definition is void: -dotimes" Error

Tags: debugging, dash.el

I'm trying to use the following function (extracted from the amazing [emacs-prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude) configuration)

```el
(defun prelude-duplicate-current-line-or-region (arg)
  "Duplicates the current line or region ARG times.
If there's no region, the current line will be duplicated.  However, if
there's a region, all lines that region covers will be duplicated."
  (interactive "p")
  (pcase-let* ((origin (point))
               (`(,beg . ,end) (prelude-get-positions-of-line-or-region))
               (region (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end)))
    (-dotimes arg
      (lambda (n)
        (goto-char end)
        (newline)
        (insert region)
        (setq end (point))))
    (goto-char (+ origin (* (length region) arg) arg))))
```

But I get the following error:

```
symbol's function definition is void: -dotimes
```

Any ideas why do I get this error? Do I have a library missing or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-dotimes` function, and many other functions starting with a dash, can be found in the `dash` library.  It's available on [GNU ELPA](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/dash.html) and [MELPA](https://stable.melpa.org/#/dash).

(Not to be confused with [`dotimes`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Iteration.html#index-dotimes), without a dash, which is built in to Emacs.)